# Formatting column separator in a table

Tags: tables, two-column

I have made a table in LaTeX. The image of the table is given below:

[image]

The code of the table is as follows:

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
    \caption{Actors vs Positional Dynamicity (based on Closeness Centrality) in Different LSNs} \label{pos1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c| c| c| c| c|}  
        \hline

        Actor\\ No. & LSN 1 & LSN 2 & LSN 3 & ...  & LSN 60   \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline\hline
        1 &0.205602  &0.262515  & 0.247979  &... & 0.170467  \\ 
        \hline
        2 &0.00961852  &0.0200901  & 0.0207746  &... & 0.107013 \\
        \hline
        3 &0.1271  & 0.170967 &  0.199928  &... &0.173208  \\
        \hline
        4 & 0.00263733 & 0.00524802 & 0.00787202  &... &0.0100803  \\
        \hline
        5 & 0.00300429 &0.00597824  &  0.00673418  &... & 0.00706005 \\ 
        \hline
        ... & ... & ... & ...   &...  .  &...    \\
        \hline
        1899 &0.00994494  &0.00968842  & 0.0216411   &...&0.0610909  \\
        \hline 
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Is there any way to properly fit the width of the column separator (marked in red in the image)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `makecell`, which allows for line breaks in cells, and `hhline` to have nicer intersection double lines, or use some colour in the table.
Here are aretwo solutions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{makecell, caption, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\colorlet{tbgcolour}{Gainsboro!70!Lavender!50! white}
\captionsetup{font=small}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering\sisetup{table-format=1.8, table-number-alignment=center}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5pt}
    \caption{Actors vs Positional Dynamicity (based on Closeness Centrality) in Different LSNs} \label{pos1}
    \begin{tabular}{|c||*{3}{S|} c|S|}
        \hhline{-||-----|}
        \makecell{Actor\\ No. } & {LSN 1} & {LSN 2} & {LSN 3} & ... & {LSN 60} \\ [0.5ex]
        \hhline{=::=====}
        1 &0.205602 &0.262515 & 0.247979 &... & 0.170467 \\
        \hhline{-||-----|}
        2 &0.00961852 &0.0200901 & 0.0207746 &... & 0.107013 \\
        \hhline{-||-----|}
        3 &0.1271 & 0.170967 & 0.199928 &... &0.173208 \\
        \hhline{-||-----|}
        4 & 0.00263733 & 0.00524802 & 0.00787202 &... &0.0100803 \\
        \hhline{-||-----|}
        5 & 0.00300429 &0.00597824 & 0.00673418 &... & 0.00706005 \\
        \hhline{-||-----|}
        ... & ... & ... & ... &... . &... \\
        \hhline{-||-----|}
        1899 &0.00994494 &0.00968842 & 0.0216411 &...&0.0610909 \\
        \hhline{-||-----|}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering\sisetup{table-format=1.8, table-number-alignment=center}
    \caption{Actors vs Positional Dynamicity (based on Closeness Centrality) in Different LSNs} \label{pos1}
\arrayrulecolor{DarkOrange!50}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{0.6pt}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{tbgcolour}[\tabcolsep][\tabcolsep]}c!{\hspace{0.5ex}}*{3}{|S}|c|S|}%
\rowcolor{tbgcolour} \multicolumn{1}{c!{\color{white}\vrule width 4.4pt}}{\makecell{Actor\\ No.}} & \multicolumn{1}{!{\color{tbgcolour}\vrule\hspace{-2\arrayrulewidth}}c}{LSN 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{LSN 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{LSN 3} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{...} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{LSN 60} \\
\addlinespace[1ex]
        \cline{2-6}
        1 & 0.205602 &0.262515 & 0.247979 &... & 0.170467 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        2 & 0.00961852 &0.0200901 & 0.0207746 &... & 0.107013 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        3 & 0.1271 & 0.170967 & 0.199928 &... &0.173208 \\
       \cline{2-6}
        4 & 0.00263733 & 0.00524802 & 0.00787202 &... &0.0100803 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        5 & 0.00300429 &0.00597824 & 0.00673418 &... & 0.00706005 \\
        \cline{2-6}
        ... & ... & ... & ... &... . &... \\
        \cline{2-6}
        1899 & 0.00994494 &0.00968842 & 0.0216411 &...&0.0610909 \\
        \cline{2-6}
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please always provide a complete (but minimal) `.tex` file when asking questions like these.

Here are two methods:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c||c| c| c| c| c|}
        \hline
        Actor &&&&&\\
        No. & LSN 1 & LSN 2 & LSN 3 & ...  & LSN 60   \\
        \hline\hline
        \shortstack{Actor\\ No.} & LSN 1 & LSN 2 & LSN 3 & ...  & LSN 60
        \\ [0.5ex]
        \hline\hline
        1 &0.205602  &0.262515  & 0.247979  &... & 0.170467  \\
        \hline
        2 &0.00961852  &0.0200901  & 0.0207746  &... & 0.107013 \\
        \hline
        3 &0.1271  & 0.170967 &  0.199928  &... &0.173208  \\
        \hline
        4 & 0.00263733 & 0.00524802 & 0.00787202  &... &0.0100803  \\
        \hline
        5 & 0.00300429 &0.00597824  &  0.00673418  &... & 0.00706005 \\
        \hline
        ... & ... & ... & ...   &...  .  &...    \\
        \hline
        1899 &0.00994494  &0.00968842  & 0.0216411   &...&0.0610909  \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Personally, I would avoid this whole style of table and use something like the one given in answer to your [other, nearly identical question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355729/8528).

Comment: You should `\centering`, not the `center` environment, which adds unwanted vertical spacing.

Comment: @Bernard -- True. I only wrote this answer to address the specific question asked. It is CW because I do not want ownership of tables designed in this fashion and because his earlier question already has an answer that shows how to design a professional table for `IEEEtran`, which is where this will end up. (+1 for your answer, but it is inappropriate, in my view, for sober scholarly work.)

Comment: I had not seen it was for an `IEEEtran` paper. That said, I think the first table I propose is quite sober. I agree the  second is more for a book, although changing the rules colour to the same gray as the background is acceptable.

Comment: @Bernard -- True enough, hence the +1 (though I fear I've fallen for Fear's rules and tend to turn up my nose at vertical rules in tables more than maybe is strictly necessary). In the right context, I'm certainly not opposed to a [little colour in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112451/8528), and the coloured table in your answer would be nice in the right kind of book.

Comment: I mostly agree with ‘no vertical rules’ *in general*, but there are exceptions (I've given some examples with just one vertical and one horizontal rules). I prefer in general some subdued fanciness in conceiving tables, if the context makes it possible. B.t.w. , ‘Fear's rules’ are not strictly  Fear's, I fear ;o)

Comment: @Bernard -- Ha, true. But 'Fear's rules' just sounds better.